# Notify users of new logged heartbeat activity

Tags: notifications, heartbeat

I am using [Heartbeat](https://www.drupal.org/project/heartbeat) module for a notification system, I've created a pop up block which shows all the logged activity targeted to a certain user. Is there a way to alert the targeted users of new logged activities.

For example, like the notifications on Facebook or twitter?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/notify) or [Notifications](https://www.drupal.org/project/notifications) module. I think from these modules you can solve your query.

Comment: Thanks I will look into Notify module since Notifications is still dev for drupal 7.

Comment: OK try once then update here if you got success or any issue.

Comment: How do I use Notify module to be something like facebook like notifications?